# Android file picker from external storage not working on API level > 24

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, android-camera-intent

I have running code of choose `file` from `file manager` , its working fine on `API level 23` but after that it is giving problem on latest devices. Now by google i knew that to use it on latest device i need to use content provider , i applied some code but it's not working . I want only path of `selected file and file will be audio`.

Manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.contentproviderfilechoose"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Java code:

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                Uri uri = null;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                requestStoragePermission();
            }




 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

             Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            //selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(MainActivity.this, selectedFileUri);


        } else { // Result was a failure
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture wasn't taken!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Not getting path of selected file

Comment: You do not need any permission to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT. So please adapt code. Further remove the flag where you grant a read permission as you cannot grand anything there. Further you will receive a nice content uri in on activity result. Use that instead of trying to make a file path from it. (For which you did not show any code... So why complain?). It is unclear for what you should need a content provider. Or what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

**Please add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in AndroidManifist.xml file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.contentproviderfilechoose"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>


here android:authorities="your_package_name.contentproviderfilechoose"

Answer (score 0):

here you may get error 
**android:authorities="your_package_name.contentproviderfilechoose"**

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.contentproviderfilechoose"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```